# Magento 2 Db migrate

Tags: magento2, database, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I'm having a magento with thousands of product and attributes. I have to just add the product in new install magento without any configuration changes in new magento. Any option to migrate database to database in magento 2.

Comment: Are you migrating Magento 2 to Magento 2 (same version, just different store) or Magento 1 -> Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data migration tool to migrate your products and attributes. You will need to set your parameters to exclude all other data. You can migrate your existing M1 Database to M2. If you don't need your setting and other data you can simply export your products from your old database and import them to your new M2 store.

You can see for documentation here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool.html